# ¿Como obtener el porcentaje de una consulta agrupada en Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, querybuilder, porcentaje

tengo el siguiente código:

```
$payment_per_bank = InvoicePayment::selectRaw('sum(amount) as amount')
        ->selectRaw('((amount * 100) / sum(amount)) AS average')
        ->groupBy('payment_type')
        ->get();
```

eso me devuelve una colección con 3 arrays como el siguiente:

```
#items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\InvoicePayment
         attributes: array:2 [▼
             "amount" => "240.00"
             "average" => "17.916667"
          ]
    1 => App\Models\InvoicePayment
         attributes: array:2 [▼
             "amount" => "160.00"
             "average" => "19.375000"
           ]
    2 => App\Models\InvoicePayment
          attributes: array:2 [▼
             "amount" => "45.00"
             "average" => "6.666667"
           ]
```

El monto lo devuelve bien, el problema es el porcentaje. La formula debería ser: **(amount * 100 / total_amount)**
Ejemplo: Ya que el monto total sería **445**, entonces el primer average debería ser: **240 * 100 / 445** que daría como resultado **53,93%**

**Average 1: 53,93%**
**Average 2: 35,95%**
**Average 3: 10,11%**

Quisiera saber como modificar la consulta para que me dé el resultado deseado. De antemano, gracias.

Comment: ¿Lo que deseas saber es el porcentaje que representa cada elemento de la columna amount?

Comment: Si, deseo saber el porcentaje que representa cada grupo en base al amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No soy un conocedor de laravel, pero la consulta SQL podría ser así:

```
SELECT t.*,  
       (payment_type_total * 100 / payments_total) as payment_type_percent
FROM (
    SELECT payment_type, 
       SUM(amount) as payment_type_total, 
       (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM invoice_payments) as payments_total
    FROM invoice_payments
    GROUP BY payment_type
) t
```

Comment: Perfecto, si funcionó como esperaba. La consulta final quedó de esta forma:

`$sql = DB::select('SELECT t.*,  
        (payment_type_total * 100 / payments_total) as payment_type_percent
        FROM (
            SELECT payment_type, 
                SUM(amount) as payment_type_total, 
                (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM invoice_payments) as payments_total
            FROM invoice_payments
            GROUP BY payment_type
        ) t');`